# Editing plist from c++ code

Tags: c++, macos, plist

So I have a code written in c++. I am trying to get a user's preference through an application. Depending on the sent value, I need to update a key in the plist. I can't find any way to do so in C++. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit a plist by executing plistbuddy command using system() call. An example to add a key value pair to plist file using system() is given below.

```
system("/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \"Add :ASSET_ID string '1'\" \"/Library/Application Support/MyApp/ABC.plist\"");
```

Given below is the plistbuddy command given to system call.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :ASSET_ID string '1'" "/Library/Application Support/MyApp/ABC.plist"
```

More details on plistbuddy here - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a few things here, because from your questions it is not quite clear the setup you are working with. I'm assuming you have a cocoa app with part of the code written in c++ (maybe based on some third party GUI library, e.g. FLTK, that hides the obj-C part?).

Anyway, in my opinion the best and safest way to go about this kind of things is to write small c++ wrappers for objective-c/cocoa code in a .mm file. You can then use the proper cocoa facilities to robustly locate and manipulate the plist (your probably want to look inside `NSBundle` and `NSPropertyListSerialization` in your case).